# Not able to create parquet file in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, parquet

I'm trying to write spark data frame into a parquet file. but not able to write into parquet file folder is getting generated but not file.

```
from lib.utils import get_spark_app_config
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
from lib.logger import Log4J

if __name__ =="__main__":

    conf = get_spark_app_config()

    spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .config(conf=conf)\
        .getOrCreate()

    df = spark.read.csv("F:\P10082021\data\Salary_Data.csv",header=True)
    df.show(2)

    df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("F:\P10082021\data\Salary_Data.parquet")
```

In the above I have initialized spark and read the CSV file into spark data frame

till there it's working there is  no problem

only while writing into parquet or CSV file it's throwing an error as below

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/P10082021/Hello.py", line 23, in <module>
    df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("F:\P10082021\data\Salary_Data.parquet")
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1250, in parquet
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o67.parquet.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hadoop bin directory does not exist: C:\Users\admin\Downloads\NewSpark\hadoop\bin\bin -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:865)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.mkdirs(ChecksumFileSystem.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:354)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:874)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hadoop bin directory does not exist: C:\Users\admin\Downloads\NewSpark\hadoop\bin\bin -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinInner(Shell.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBin(Shell.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDurationHelper(Configuration.java:1814)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$HookEntry.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:302)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

In errors it says hadoop bin doesn't exist but I have set the environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you specified `HADOOP_HOME = C:\Users\admin\Downloads\NewSpark\hadoop\bin\` and `PATH = %HADOOP_HOME%\bin` and it's adding \bin again to `HADOOP_HOME` path and you are getting error.
Remove \bin in HADOOP_HOME variable.

Comment: no i specified exactly as you mentioned ```HADOOP_HOME= C:\hadoop     
PATH =%HADOOP_HOME%\bin```

Comment: Paste the output of this command here --> echo %HADOOP_HOME%

Comment: I'm getting this  C:\hadoop

Comment: Have you added winutils.exe under C:\hadoop\bin ?

Comment: Yes, Thanq. there is a conflict  between variable for admin and system variables have two different paths after giving same path it's working.